# Why I can not save data in realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I have SaveDataToRealm class. In this class I am trying to store data in realm. But I am not able to get it. When I am printing the realm object after writing it is showing the object without the values I tried to write.

```
class SaveDataToRealm: BaseViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        saveSessionData()
    }

    // MARK:-  save session and Close session
    func saveSessionData() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let localSession = TempRingSessionObject()
        if isLiveSession{
           sessionId = RandomStringGenerator.sharedInstance.getUniqueSessionString()
            localSession.sessionId = sessionId!
        } else{
            localSession.class_id = courseSetupDetails["class_id"] as! String
        }
        try! realm.write {
            realm.add(localSession)
        }
    }
```

By using `saveSessionData()` function I am initializing Realm. In `closeSelfSession()` function I am trying to store data into Realm.

```
func closeSelfSession(currentTimeStamp:String)  {   
    let realm = try! Realm()
    if !(sessionId ?? "").isEmpty{
        let session = realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId contains '\(String(describing: self.sessionId))'").last
        try! realm.write {        
            session?.score = "60"           
            session?.timeOfSession = currentTimeStamp
            session?.tempSessionData.append(objectsIn:realm.objects(TempRingDataObject.self).filter("tag = '\(tagString)'"))
        }
    } else{  
        let session =  realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId contains '\(self.courseSetupDetails["class_id"] as! String)'").last       
        try! realm.write {    
            session?.tempSessionData.append(objectsIn: realm.objects(TempRingDataObject.self).filter("tag = '\(tagString)'"))
            session?.timeOfSession = currentTimeStamp
            session?.score = "75"
        } 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `NSPredicate`s used for filtering are all flawed.

You should never use `String(describing:)` to compare variables, since depending on the exact type it might yield unexpected results. Moreover, when using single quotes in predicates, you tell the compiler to look for the exact result and not for a variable's value. You also shouldn't use String interpolation (`"\(variable)"`) when working with `NSPredicate`s, you should be using the `%@` format specifier.

```
let session = realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId contains '\(String(describing: self.sessionId))'").last
```

should actually be

```
let session = realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId CONTAINS @%",self.sessionID).last
```

This predicate `realm.objects(TempRingDataObject.self).filter("tag = '\(tagString)'")` should be

```
realm.objects(TempRingDataObject.self).filter("tag = %@",tagString)
```

And your last predicate,

```
realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId contains '\(self.courseSetupDetails["class_id"] as! String)'"
```

should be

```
realm.objects(TempRingSessionObject.self).filter("sessionId CONTAINS %@",self.courseSetupDetails["class_id"])
```